# SQL Transaction unexpectedly rolling back after commit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, rollback

We have a SQL script (to post invoices in our accounting application) like this:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  --
  --Insert/Update a lot of tables
  --
  WHILE @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRAN;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  WHILE @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRAN;
  DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000)
  DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT
  DECLARE @ErrorState INT
  SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
         @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
         @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE()
  RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
END CATCH
```

At the end of the posting of the transaction we print the transaction which involves querying the data just posted. So we know the transaction did go through - it is printed in black and white on paper!

Now this script works 99.9999% of the time across 100s of customers in busy sites posting 1000s of transactions per minute.  But randomly (1 in a 1000000) the transaction we have just posted disappears???  The whole transaction seems to have been completely rolled back.

I am wondering if SQL Server went into some recovery mode. But I can't seem to see any log of that in SSMS or Windows Event Viewer (so I do not think that is the case).  I am looking in the "Event Viewer"/"Windows Logs"/"Application". I can see older events in here for SQL Server - but they are many hours prior.

What could cause this? How can I log or trace such an event?

Comment: You can try sql profiler to see what actually is happening in sql server for this.

Comment: `WHILE @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN`? In the absence of save points you only need one rollback. The current code rolls back the entire transaction, regardless of how many nested transactions there may be. `PRINT` statements are not part of a transaction, they're in the Info Messages stream, so transactions can still get rolled back even after you've printed something.

Comment: Cant run profiler on high volume live server - this event happens extremely rarely.

Comment: Yes I am going to talk to my team about "WHILE @@TRANCOUNT >0 ROLLBACK TRAN".  FYI my printing is done in my application with completely separate SQL query.

Comment: I don't get why it works 99.9999% of the time.  But I do wonder - could the WHILE @@TRANCOUNT >0 ROLLBACK TRANS be rolling back other transactions outside of my transaction - I very much doubt it right.  Hmm we are not using save points.  Transaction is big and complex though - calling stored procedures / triggers etc as well.

Comment: Don't you observe an error : "Msg 3998 ... Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back." ? In this case your catch blocked is skipped.

Comment: Most likely there is an issue with locking and isolation levels, in other words some kind of race condition because of write skew. Without knowing your code, cannot say for sure. What, pray tell, is the point of the whole catch block, only to reraise the error? Just do `SET XACT_ABORT ON` and remove all the rest of the error handling

Comment: Have not detected a 3998 error

Comment: point of try catch is to roll back all possible execution points in the batch and to pass the result to the application.  I am going to get my main programmer to review this.  Stay tuned

Answer (score 0):

SQL Transaction  stored procedure

Try this SQL stored procedure script

```
begin tran
begin try
--
--Insert/Update a lot of tables
--

if @@trancount > 0 commit tran
end try
begin catch
if @@trancount > 0 rollback tran

DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);  
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;  
DECLARE @ErrorState INT;  

SELECT   
   @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),  
   @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),  
   @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  

RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);  

end catch
```

[sql](/questions/tagged/sql)  [sqlscript](/questions/tagged/sqlscript)  [storedprocedure](/questions/tagged/storedprocedure)

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation of what you have done such that the OP can learn from it.

Comment: We will consider/try this.  I see the point though - makes sense to have the BEGIN TRAN first.